# startsWith operator if ReplaySubject doesn't have any value emitted in RXJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a replay subject as below:

```
@Injectable()
export class ViewByService implements OnDestroy {
  private _selectedViewBy$ = new ReplaySubject<ViewByContext>(1);
  public selectedViewBy$ = this._selectedViewBy$.asObservable();
  constructor() {}
  setViewBy(viewBy: ViewByContext): void {
    this._selectedViewBy$.next(viewBy);
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._selectedViewBy$.complete();
  }
}
```

When I am subscribing after the value has been emitted I am getting the last value as expect as my `bufferCount` is 1.

**WHAT I NEED**

On consumer side when I am subscribing to this `ReplaySubject`, if it has values emitted earlier than I should get the last value but if I haven't emitted any value from this  `ReplaySubject` then I want to `startWith` some default value. But my `startWith` should only push value if there is no values emitted from `ReplaySubject`.

Now when I do this:

```
this.viewByService.selectedViewBy$.pipe(
  startWith({ code: 'DEFAULT'})
)
```

When I have no values emitted from `ReplaySubject` I am pushing `DEFAULT` which is fine but when I have values in my `ReplaySubject` then I see it is pushing both `DEFAULT` and the value which is earlier emitted.

How can we conditionally run `startWith` if and only if my `ReplaySubject` hasn't emitted any value before.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: ReplaySubject with 1 is similar with BehaviorSubject. How will that solve this problem?

Comment: Because you intialise a behavior subject with a default value

Comment: With BehaviorSubject can I get the last value even when I subscribe post emission of that value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But as you say, `BehaviorSubject()` acts in the same way as `ReplaySubject(1)`, except `BehaviorSubject` emits the initial value until a new value is passed in via `next()`

Comment: Yeah but with BehaviorSubject I will always get 2 values. Basically I am subscribing post the values are actually emitted. So ReplaySubject was a better match...

Comment: Why do you get 2 values with `BehaviorSubject`? Can you create a stackblitz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212279/discussion-between-siddharth-pal-and-kurt-hamilton).

Comment: I think `BehaviorSubject` is what you're looking for. The default value is automatically overridden by every `next() call.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider to use a `BehaviorSubject` in combination with `shareReply` operator, like this

```
const b = new BehaviorSubject<any>({ code: 'DEFAULT'});
const s = b.pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

If `b` emits before you subscribe, then when you subscribe `shareReply` ensures you get the last value emitted.

If you subscribe before `b` emits any value, when you subscribe you get the default value defined in the `BehaviorSubject` constructor.